# How to get the usable width of the window's main menu?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui

Say, I have a Win32 app with a menu added to the main window via `CreateWindowEx` method, and I need to know its usable width. The best way to illustrate the width I'm asking for is with this diagram:

[image]

So how do I calculate it?

When I try to do the following, it gives me the width of the client area:

```
MENUBARINFO mbi = {0};
mbi.cbSize = sizeof(mbi);
if(::GetMenuBarInfo(hWnd, OBJID_MENU, 0, &mbi))
{
    int nUsableWifth = mbi.rcBar.right - mbi.rcBar.left;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean usable? The "usable" width **is** the client area, and the menu will use the whole width if it needs to. `GetMenuItemRect()` will get you the position of a specific menu item.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: See the red arrow on the diagram above. Whatever you would call it.

Comment: I can see the red arrow, but that's not "usable width", it's simply the width necessary to display the menu as it currently exists.

Comment: So if you want the right-edge of the "Help" item, use `GetMenuItemRect()`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: OK, we're going into a nomenclature here. Let's call it a `pink elephant` if you want.

Comment: I'd prefer you called it something meaningful to make it easier to answer your question. You've been on SO long enough to know how important nomenclature is.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I would argue that the right edge would not be an ideal name. What if the window is too small. In either case it's pointless to discuss words here, isn't it? To help understand my question I gave you a diagram (i.e. a picture.)

Comment: But your picture is not descriptive enough. It now sounds like you want the minimum width needed to display the menu without wrapping? But I'm not sure, I'm having to guess.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: OK. I don't know how else to describe it. Let's reverse it to make it more clear. I need to calculate the coordinates of the part of the menu bar that does not have clickable buttons: "File", "Format", "Reports", "Tools" and "Help" in the diagram above. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: ... but I see now that I can do it by calling `GetMenuItemRect` on indices 0 thru last menu item (`GetMenuItemCount` - 1) and get a combined area of all results.

Comment: So the question is -- is it worth dragging it for this long instead of just posting a solution?

Comment: It's not possible to post a solution without understanding the question, which I didn't (and honestly not sure I yet do).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Can they wrap around vertically if the client area is too short, or be configured to be displayed vertically?

Comment: @c00000fd: Yes, they can wrap around, I didn't notice that before.  Well, in that case, you are stuck looping through all of the items one at a time looking for the highest right-edge coordinate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the width that is used for menu items, you can either:

1. use `GetMenuItemRect()` to get the *screen coordinates* of the last menu item, and then convert them to *client coordinates* within the parent window.  The converted right edge coordinate will give you the width:

   ```
   HMENU hMenu = ::GetMenu(hWnd);
   int count = ::GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
   RECT r;
   if (::GetMenuItemRect(hWnd, hMenu, count-1, &r))
   {
       ::MapWindowPoints(NULL, hWnd, (LPPOINT)&r, 2);
       int nUsedWidth = r.right;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. the above assumes the menu starts at offset 0 within the window's client area. If you don't want to rely on that, you could instead get the *screen coordinates* of the 1st menu item and subtract it from the right-edge *screen coordinate* of the last menu item:

   ```
   HMENU hMenu = ::GetMenu(hWnd);
   int count = ::GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
   RECT rFirst, rLast;
   if (::GetMenuItemRect(hWnd, hMenu, 0, &rFirst) &&
       ::GetMenuItemRect(hWnd, hMenu, count-1, &rLast))
   {
       int nUsedWidth = rLast.right - rFirst.left;
       ...
   }
   ```

Either way, if you then want to know the width that is not used for menu items, simply get the menu's total width and subtract the above calculated width:

```
MENUBARINFO mbi = {0};
mbi.cbSize = sizeof(mbi);
if (::GetMenuBarInfo(hWnd, OBJID_MENU, 0, &mbi))
{
    int nUsableWidth = (mbi.rcBar.right - mbi.rcBar.left) - nUsedWidth;
    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: I didn't realize a window's menu can wrap its items vertically if the client area is too small to display them all on one line.  In that case, you might have to do something more like this instead to calculate `nUsedWidth`:

```
HMENU hMenu = ::GetMenu(hWnd);
int count = ::GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
int nUsedWidth = 0;
RECT r;

for(int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
{
    if (::GetMenuItemRect(hWnd, hMenu, idx, &r))
    {
        ::MapWindowPoints(NULL, hWnd, (LPPOINT)&r, 2);
        if (r.right > nUsedWidth)
            nUsedWidth = r.right;
    }
}
...
```

Or:

```
HMENU hMenu = ::GetMenu(hWnd);
int count = ::GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
int nUsedWidth = 0;
RECT rFirst, r;

if (::GetMenuItemRect(hWnd, hMenu, 0, &rFirst))
{
    nUsedWidth = rFirst.right - rFirst.left;
    for (int idx = 1; idx < count; ++idx)
    {
        if (::GetMenuItemRect(hWnd, hMenu, idx, &r))
        {
            int nWidth = r.right - rFirst.left;
            if (nWidth > nUsedWidth)
                nUsedWidth = nWidth;
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why were you calling `MapWindowPoints` API on the coordinates though?

Comment: Because `GetMenuItemRect()` returns **screen coordinates**, so I was converting them to **client coordinates**.